# How to solve this Complex Integral using poles?

Tags: complex-integration, greens-function, cauchy-principal-value

I want to find the green's function of a free particle, which depends of the integral:
$$
I = \frac{1}{4\pi ²ir} \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{ke^{ikr}}{E-\frac{\hbar²k²}{2m}+i\eta} dk\,.
$$

Then, using the cauchy principal value we remove the $\eta$...The result is as follows:

$$
g=\frac{e^{i\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}r}}{4\pi r}
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with contour integration?

Comment: I know that I need to use something like a contour integral + integral from -R to R with R-> Infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints:

1. Get your integral in more combined form:
   $$ I(r) = \int \frac{k e^{i k r}}{A - k^2} $$
   here $A$ is constant. Forget about everything else till the end.
2. Think of the function $F(r)$, s. t. 
   $$ F'(r) = I(r) $$
3. Draw some contours and see which one is better for $F(r)$. If nothing comes to mind, try literature, I would recommend: Russell L. Herman, An introduction to mathematical physics via oscillations
4. Now return to your preintegral constant and substitute A.